# Elegant way to change input variables from default in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I have a shiny app that basically follows the following setup:

```
library(shiny)

weights <- data.frame("weights" = c(1, 2))

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage(

   # Application title
   titlePanel("Old Faithful Geyser Data"),

   # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins 
   sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
         sliderInput("variable1",
                     "Weight 1",
                     min = 1,
                     max = 50,
                     value = weights[1,])
      ),

      # Show a plot of the generated distribution
      mainPanel(
         plotOutput("distPlot")
      )
   )
)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {

   output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
      # generate bins based on input$bins from ui.R
      x    <- faithful[, 1]*input$variable1

      bins <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = input$bins + 1)

      # draw the histogram with the specified number of bins
      hist(x, breaks = bins, col = 'darkgray', border = 'white')
   })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

But I have +100 different variables, so actually duplicating each line of this code 100 hundred times (like this) seems cumbersome:

```
x    <- faithful[, 1]*input$variable1
y    <- faithful[, 1]*input$variable2
z    <- faithful[, 1]*input$variable3

xx <- x+y+z # I would plot xx
```

Is there a more elegant solution i'm missing? Maybe with a reactive function?

Comment: Do you want to plot 100+ histograms?

Comment: I don't understand which part has 100 different variables. Are you saying that it goes from `faithful[, 1]` to `faithful[,100]` but they all use the same `input$bins`? Do you want 100 different plot outputs? What exactly is the desired output?

Comment: sorry, I edited to make it more explicit...

Comment: are you going to build the 100+ input variables by hand

Comment: @HubertL in the UI yes, (the user has to be able to play with each)...

Comment: if you are sure about the 100 variables, you could try sthg like: `rowSums(sapply(1:100, function(var) faithful[, 1]*input[[paste0("variable", var)]]))`

Comment: I am still unclear about the `100+ variables`. Are you saying that the UI will have `100+` user inputs?

Comment: @Drj yep, exactly!

Comment: @eflores89 you saw my comment?

Comment: @BigDataScientist yes that seems right!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As written in the comment i would suggest sthg like:

`rowSums(sapply(1:100, function(var) faithful[, 1]*input[[paste0("variable", var)]]))`

You can find a reproducible example (with 2 inputs) below:

```
library(shiny)
weights <- data.frame("weights" = c(1, 2))
ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      sliderInput("variable1", "Weight 1",min = 1, max = 50, value = weights[1,]),
      sliderInput("variable2", "Weight 2",min = 1, max = 50, value = weights[2,])
    ),
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("distPlot")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
    data <- rowSums(sapply(1:2, function(var) faithful[, 1]*input[[paste0("variable", var)]]))
    hist(data, col = 'darkgray', border = 'white')
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: if it fulfills your requirements i would appreeciate an upvote :)